# How do you provide breaks (and colors) manually for binned continuous data in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Often I would like to bin a continuous variable when I plot it with `ggplot`. In the example below, it will be the fill aesthetic. It seems that both `scale_fill_binned` and `scale_fill_stepn` should be able to do the job yet I struggle to manually specify breaks and colors for data that doesn't plot neatly on a linear scale.

In the example below, both very small negative numbers as well as large positive ones are present. So I might want to have a distinct color for negative values (say, red) and a higher resolution for small positive values than in the default of `scale_fill_binned`.

However, when I manually add breaks the lower three bins all have the same color. What would be the best way to bin continuous data while maintaining some control over the position of the breaks and the color scheme? Is it necessary to go fully manual with `cut()` and `scale_fill_manual()` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363155/ggplot-geom-tile-plot-continuous-variable-using-irregular-user-defined-discr)?

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

# create dummy data
df <- expand_grid(
  color = c("red", "green", "blue"),
  temperature = c("cold", "neutral", "hot")
) %>% mutate(
  value = unlist(map(c(0, 1, 10000), ~ rnorm(3, mean = .x)))
)

knitr::kable(df)
```

| color | temperature | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | cold | -0.6264538 |
| red | neutral | 0.1836433 |
| red | hot | -0.8356286 |
| green | cold | 2.5952808 |
| green | neutral | 1.3295078 |
| green | hot | 0.1795316 |
| blue | cold | 10000.4874291 |
| blue | neutral | 10000.7383247 |
| blue | hot | 10000.5757814 |

```r
# plot with default breaks
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(color, temperature, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_binned()
```

[image]

```r
# plot with manual breaks
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(color, temperature, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_binned(breaks = c(-10, 0, 1, 2, 1000, 5000, 10000))
```

[image]

Created on 2021-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use specific filling colors when using scale\_fill\_binned()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318404/how-to-use-specific-filling-colors-when-using-scale-fill-binned)