# Setting values for scale_colour_gradientn in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use scale_colour_gradientn to clearly show neg vs pos values: negative is blue, positive is red.  But gradientn seems to ignore my vector of colors, and just makes one big gradient instead of n small gradients.  Here's my sample code ...

```
xx <- -100:100
yy <- xx
fma <- data.frame( xx, yy)
ggplot( fma) +
  geom_point( aes( xx, yy, col=yy)) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    colours=c('#0000ff','#0000ff','#ff0000','#ff0000'),
    values=c(  -100,       -1,      1,      100))
```

How can I convince gradientn to color everything in [-100,-1] blue and everything in [1,100] red?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487369/ggplot-set-scale-color-gradientn-manually (the values should go from 0 to 1, they do not correspond to the values in your data).

Comment: From the docs for `scale_color_gradientn` regarding `values`: if colours should not be evenly positioned along the gradient this vector gives the position (between 0 and 1) for each colour in the colours vector.

Comment: Thanks, the comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `scale_color_continuous`, I'd make a `factor` variable that tells what color to color those points and use `scale_color_discrete` or `*_manual`. In this example, we use a conditional in the `aes` so `col` receives either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the value of `yy`, but if you wanted more possible values, you could use `switch` or `case_when` to populate a `yy_range` variable with the possible color categories.

```
ggplot(fma) +
    geom_point(aes( xx, yy, col = yy < 0)) +
    scale_color_discrete(c('#0000ff','#ff0000'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

if you'd like to keep the color scale as a gradient, instead of a dichotemous scale, you could do this:

```
xx <- -100:100
yy <- xx
fma <- data.frame( xx, yy)
ggplot( fma) +
  geom_point( aes( xx, yy, col=yy)) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    colours=c('indianred4','indianred1','white','darkseagreen1','darkseagreen4'),
    values=c(  0,       49.5,  50,    50.5,      100)/100)
```

[image]

the values-argument only takes values between 0 and 1, which means that in your case, -100 is equal to 0, and 100 is 1.

I have added the color white, which corresponds to ~0, for neutrality. This white range could be expanded, by setting .495 to something like .40, and .50 to .50

also notice that I'm making a vector for the values argument without decimals, for convenience and readability, and then dividing it with a 100, to rescale it so the values argument can use it.